# ng-repeat not displaying the data in table format

Tags: angularjs, jsp, view, angularjs-ng-repeat, tabular

The below code snippet need to print the  toolDTO object (i.e. Array of object and each object has key and value pairs).

```
<div ng-show="isResult" style="color: green;">
                    <table class="tble">
                        <thead>
                            <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in toolDTO[0]" align="center"
                                style="background: #7e7e7e; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: small;">
                                <th><b>{{key}}</b></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody ng-repeat="tool in toolDTO">                         
                            <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in tool"
                                style="font-size: small;">
                                <td>{{value}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

toolDTO structures:

```
 [
        {
            "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER": "1234",
            "FIRST_NAME": "Ram",
            "LAST_NAME": "Rakul",
            "EMAIL": "Ram.Rakul@example.com",
            "UPDATED_BY": 5678,
            "UPDATED_DATE": "2018-01-23 17:25:42.635"
        },
        {
            "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER": "45678",
            "FIRST_NAME": "vinod",
            "LAST_NAME": "nai",
            "EMAIL": "vinto.nani@example.com",
            "UPDATED_BY": 5678,
            "UPDATED_DATE": "2018-01-12 20:38:50.191"
        },

    ]
```

The ng repeat code printing the above data like below.

```
      EMAIL 
      EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
      FIRST_NAME
      LAST_NAME
      UPDATED_DATE
      UPDATED_BY
     Ram.Rakul@example.com
     1234
     Ram
     Rakul
     2018-01-23 17:25:42.635
     5678
```

But I need it  below table format:

```
EMPLOYEE_NUMBER  FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME EMAIL  UPDATED_BY   UPDATED_DATE
 1234            Ram        Rakul    Ram.Rakul@example.com 5678        2018-01-23.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to repeat `thead > th` element for table headers not `thead > tr`. Also repeat `tbody > td` not `tbody > tr` for rows.

```
<div ng-show="isResult" style="color: green;">
                    <table class="tble">
                        <thead>
                            <tr align="center" style="background: #7e7e7e; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: small;">
                                <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in toolDTO[0]"><b>{{key}}</b></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody ng-repeat="tool in toolDTO">
                            <tr style="font-size: small;">
                                <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in tool">{{value}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: How to retain the same data order in table headers and value.  In data its is in order of employeenumber,first name, last name , email etc . But in Ng repeat it shuffles the data and display in order of EMAIL EMPLOYEENUMBER,FIRSTNAME ,LASTNAME etc . Any hint on How to maintain the same data order.